# Window-Leveling in python

Tags: python, image, dicom

I would like to change the window-level of my dicom images from lung window to chest window. I know the values need for the window-leveling. But how to implement it in python? Or else anyone can provide me with an detailed description of this process would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you had a look at the description of windowing in the DICOM Standard? http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.11.2.html#sect_C.11.2.1.2 Or what else does your question refer to?

Answer (score 2):

I have already implemented this in Python. Take a look at the function GetImage in [dicomparser](https://github.com/dicompyler/dicompyler-core/blob/master/dicompylercore/dicomparser.py) module in the [dicompyler-core](https://github.com/dicompyler/dicompyler-core) library.

Essentially it follows what kritzel_sw suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Following open source code can implement bone window.

```
def get_pixels_hu(slices):
    image = numpy.stack([s.pixel_array for s in slices])
    image = image.astype(numpy.int16)
    image[image == -2000] = 0
    for slice_number in range(len(slices)):
        intercept = slices[slice_number].RescaleIntercept
        slope = slices[slice_number].RescaleSlope
        if slope != 1:
            image[slice_number] = slope * image[slice_number].astype(numpy.float64)
            image[slice_number] = image[slice_number].astype(numpy.int16)
        image[slice_number] += numpy.int16(intercept)

    return numpy.array(image, dtype=numpy.int16)
```

And i added following code

```
image[slice_number] = image[slice_number]*3.5 + mean2*0.1
```

after
    image[slice_number] += numpy.int16(intercept)
can change bone window to brain tissue window.
The point is setting of parameter 3.5 and 0.1. I just tried and got these two parameters suitable for brain tissue window. Maybe you can adjust them for chest window.